# "Условные предложения вежливости"

Tags: синтаксис

В испанском языке мы имеем такое явление как "условные предложения вежливости". Это предложения tipo "если вас не затруднит", "если вы не против", "если вы мне позволите бестактность"... Я сомневаюсь, можно ли считать такие предложения настоящими СПП условия, так как они не выражают как такового условия по сравнению с такими предложениями как "если идет дождь, улицы мокрые". Скажите, пожалуйста, как Вы их рассматривали бы синтаксически? Тоже как условные?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По значению это тоже "предложения вежливости", отнесенные к какой-либо просьбе. Грамматически эти предложения могут строиться **как обычные сложные предложения с придаточным условным**, но также могут иметь вид **вводного предложения,** не связанного с грамматикой основного сообщения.

Примеры:

1) **Если вас не затруднит**, купите ей что-нибудь от моего имени. **Если вас не затруднит**, откройте, пожалуйста, эту дверь.

2) Ну, что ж, **если вас не затруднит**, то кофе и рюмка коньяка были бы в самый раз: погода сегодня премерзкая.

Уже упомянутое мною лицо приглашает вас послезавтра к себе. Утром, **если вас не затруднит**. Адрес ― тот же».

**Если вас не затруднит,** наш номер такой-то».

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! извините, у меня еще один вопрос появился: 
"Если бы он был умный, разве согласился бы на эту авантю́ру?" - можно считать такие предложения условными, если главное предложение оформлено как вопрос? или это не имеет влияние?

Comment: Это частный вид условного предложения, синонимичного следующему  предложению: Если бы он был умный, то он не согласился бы   на эту авантю́ру. Здесь в главной части содержится риторический вопрос, который является экспрессивной формой отрицания.